# Running an updatemany statement in Mongo when your items are in a list

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

What I'm trying to do is update the location UUID across many different documents, all within the same space.

The data that I'm wanting to update looks like this where I'm wanting to change the UUID.

```
 "Location" : {
        "Id" : UUID("abcd-efgh-1234-5678"),
        "Name" : "Lot A",
        "Code" : "A"
```

I'm trying to use this which is what I found through google searches but it doesn't appear to be going the way I want.

db.getCollection('collections').updateMany({UUID: {$in: [("abcd-efgh-1234-5678")]}}, {$set: {UUID: "NEW UUID"}}, false, true) )

I feel like this is close but again, all the google searches don't seem to lead me down the path. I understand how to do it if it was just UUID but the Location:ID:UUID is throwing me off.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
db.getCollection('collections').updateMany(
      {
        "Location.Id": { 
                        $in: ["UUID1","UUID2"]
                       }
       },
       {
         $set: {"Location.Id": "NEW UUID"}
       }
      )
```

[exmple](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2f-vMAOAzfJ)

Comment: So I think I had a variation  of that before but just tried again. I updated the UUID1 to the actual UUID and the new one, when running in Robo it acknowledges but says it found 0. In Mongo it says "not primary"